# Azure and F# 3.0 Type Providers

Tags: f#, azure-sql-database, type-providers, f#-3.0

Do F# 3.0 Type Providers work with SQL Azure? I'm getting an error while trying. Wondering if there are any known issues with this.

Comment: Could you expand on the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it. I needed to use EntityTypeProvider instead of SqlServerProvider.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked. It is used with SqlEntityConnection<>, but should be defined as internal type.